# mysql get month number not relative to the year

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to get results month by month for the last 3 years. This is what I have:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `by_year`()
BEGIN
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS  aaa;
    SET @year = 2014;
    WHILE @year <= YEAR(CURDATE()) DO
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aaa (Año int, Registrados int,  Activos int, Compraron int, Recurrentes int);
        INSERT INTO aaa 
        SELECT @year, registrados.count, activos.count, compraron.count, recurrentes.count FROM

        # Here is my query to get the data. With a WHERE that limits the creation date by @year. [YEAR(AU.created) <= @year] For example

    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM aaa;
END
```

It works for years. But I need to get the result by months or even weeks and days.

My problem is if I replace the YEAR function with MONTH or DAY These functions will return a number taken from the date literally (relative to the bigger divider)

For example from

```
MONTH('2015-11-25')
```

I get

```
11
```

So MONTH('2015-11-25') is equal to MONTH('2016-11-02')

I see two ways... Either I find a function or something like:

```
MONTH_FROM_THE_BEGGINING_OF_TIMES('2016-11-02')
```

That similarly to dates handled by TIME, returns the month number in general in this case from year 1 that should be somenthing like (2015 * 12) + 11 = 24191

The other way could be playing around with double WHILE. And then for days triple WHILE. This will produce a complexity of O(n^3) which is not good.

Any ideas are very welcome.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get some kind of aggregate value by month for the previous 3 years?

Comment: Correct. @Bill Karwin gave me the answer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like MySQL's [EXTRACT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) function:

```
mysql> SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURDATE()) AS YM;
+--------+
| YM     |
+--------+
| 201608 |
+--------+
```

If you want days, you might like [TO_DAYS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days):

```
mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS(CURDATE()) AS days;
+--------+
| days   |
+--------+
| 736564 |
+--------+
```

Comment: @Alejandro, Why don't you try following the link I gave to the documentation for the `EXTRACT()` function and find out! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cant not replace the function YEAR, you just need to add the function MONTH to get the result by months with the logical AND operator. Also in your query to get the data you have to add the AND part for the month at the group by. 
It is the only way to get the month number relative to the year.